# Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" => Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML => User still logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I click 'log out' I can see that Rails processess the request, but I'm still logged in.
Any clue why this happens? Both locally and on Heroku.

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for IP at 2014-11-18 08:32:46 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"TOKEN"}
Redirected to http://example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
Started GET "/" for 84.215.64.133 at 2014-11-18 08:32:47 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#blog as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/blog.html.slim within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 2.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users
```

From the log when editing a user:

```
Started PUT "/users" for 84.215.64.133 at 2014-11-18 14:40:30 +0000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QR/p3BAG+ocmacss5xDjuFDfhFSA+iv6VRK37uA9HcQ=", "user"=>{"mobile"=>"93441707", "email"=>"sss@
strosin.info", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Lagre"}
2014-11-18T14:40:31.095730+00:00 app[web.2]: App 131 stdout: Redirected to http://
```

Comment: "authenticity_token" should not be "THKEN"

Comment: have you wrapped your log out button into a <% if user_signed_in? %>?

Comment: @scottxu he's not getting `InvalidAuthenticityToken` exception, so i think he just disabled it or changed it after pasting in StackOverflow ;)

@martins How do you know that the user is still logged in?

Comment: I replaced the original long token with TOKEN. @iMacTia, I'm able to edit my profile. At least open the edit form, the changes does not get saved:

Comment: Ok, are you using the standard devise editor or a custom one in one of your controllers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem disapeared when I cleared the browser cache. (Using Chrome beta).